# Msys terminal error in opening new terminal

Tags: terminal, console, mingw-w64, msys

Sometimes when i open the msys2 mingw64 bit terminal an error is displayed in console:

```
Error: Could not fork child process: There are no available terminals (-1).
```

This error oqurues many time during the project time, but if i restart the laptop, there is no error.

Anyone who has facing simillar error?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue too, and it disappears after reboot.

Make sure you have run `autorebase.bat` in the msys64 folder.